# Using transform with condition within a dataframe

Tags: pandas, transform

Have the following `df`

```
import numpy as np
import random

i = ['dog', 'cat', 'rabbit', 'elephant'] * 20

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(i), 3), index=i, \
            columns=list('ABC')).rename_axis('animal').reset_index()
            
df.insert(1, 'type', pd.Series(random.choice(['X', 'Y']) \
                for _ in range(len(df))))
```

I would like to have the `max` of column A, if the type of the animal is X ... else the `min` of column A, in a separate column.

Apply lambda with group by shows the multi-indexed array with the following code:

```
g = df.groupby(['animal', 'type'])
g.apply(lambda g: np.where (g.type == 'X', g.A.max(), g.A.min()))
```

Is there a way to convert this to a series, that can be added to df as a column... say by using `transform`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
>>> df

     animal type     A     B     C
0       cat    Y  0.96 -0.02 -0.14
1       cat    Y -0.80  0.86  1.75
2       dog    X  1.13 -0.49 -1.66
3       dog    Y  0.84 -0.07  0.15
4  elephant    X  0.13 -0.54  0.73
5  elephant    Y  0.14  1.77  0.94
6    rabbit    X -0.12 -0.39  0.05
7    rabbit    X  0.58 -1.17  0.77

>>> def max_min_A(g):
        animal, type_ = g.name 
        return np.where(type_ == 'X', g.max(), g.min())

>>> df['new_col'] = df.groupby(['animal', 'type'])['A'].transform(max_min_A)

     animal type     A     B     C  new_col
0       cat    Y  0.96 -0.02 -0.14    -0.80
1       cat    Y -0.80  0.86  1.75    -0.80
2       dog    X  1.13 -0.49 -1.66     1.13
3       dog    Y  0.84 -0.07  0.15     0.84
4  elephant    X  0.13 -0.54  0.73     0.13
5  elephant    Y  0.14  1.77  0.94     0.14
6    rabbit    X -0.12 -0.39  0.05     0.58
7    rabbit    X  0.58 -1.17  0.77     0.58
```

Comment: Series have an [`name` attribute](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.name.html) as you may know. Each column group is passed to the `transform` function as a Series whose name is the group label (in this key the tuple ('animal', 'type')). I discovered it when I understood that ;) But it's in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) of `transform` under **Notes** ("Each group is endowed the attribute ‘name’ in case you need to know which group you are working on.")

Answer (score 1):

@HarryPlotter: Thx for the `name` info. It is wonderful to see that the name of the group propagates as a tuple. In case one does not want to use a function, the following will work:

```
df.assign(new_col=g.A.transform(lambda x: np.where(x.name[1] =='X', \
            x.max(), x.min()))) 
# x.name[1] is used to select the second element of the tuple, which is `type`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to think that performance wise, it is better to build the temporary columns, rather than iterating through groupby:

```py
grp = df.groupby(['animal', 'type'])['A']

(df
.assign(
    mi = grp.transform('min'), 
    ma = grp.transform('max'), 
    new_col = lambda df: np.where(df['type'] == 'X', df['ma'], df['mi']))
.drop(columns=['mi','ma'])
)
     animal type     A     B     C  new_col
0       cat    Y  0.96 -0.02 -0.14    -0.80
1       cat    Y -0.80  0.86  1.75    -0.80
2       dog    X  1.13 -0.49 -1.66     1.13
3       dog    Y  0.84 -0.07  0.15     0.84
4  elephant    X  0.13 -0.54  0.73     0.13
5  elephant    Y  0.14  1.77  0.94     0.14
6    rabbit    X -0.12 -0.39  0.05     0.58
7    rabbit    X  0.58 -1.17  0.77     0.58
```